# Gson LinkedTree map cannot be casted to InformativeItemProvider

Tags: java, gson, bukkit

**To start: I know this error is common and it might seem duplicate.

But its not, read the code and I will explain my error.**

My plugin for in this case Minecraft exists out of 3 Important classes, but only it the JSONConfig all the magic is happening:

JSONConfig.java

```
public class JSONConfig {
    private String Path;
    private Map<String,Object> config;
    private File pathfile;
    public JSONConfig(String path)
    {
        this.Path = path;
        pathfile = new File(path);
        if (pathfile.exists()){
            JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
            try {
                Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Map<String,Object>>() { }.getType();
                this.config = new Gson().fromJson(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(path)), typeOfHashMap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Core.jp.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"[InformativeItems]: Whoops, our JSONConfigReader could not read the config: "+path);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            this.config = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            try {
                FileUtils.writeStringToFile(pathfile, config.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Core.jp.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN+"[InformativeItems]: Config Loaded ("+path+")");
    }



    public Map<String,Object> getConfig(){return this.config;}

    public void reload(){
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        try {
            Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Map<String,Object>>() { }.getType();
            this.config = new Gson().fromJson(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(this.Path)), typeOfHashMap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Core.jp.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"[InformativeItems]: Whoops, our JSONConfigReader could not read the config: "+Path);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void save(){
        try {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(pathfile, gson.toJson(gson.toJsonTree(config)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

In the core i have a statement that reads the config and loops trough its values.

All the values where serialized from a config that only contained one type of class as values: InformativeItemProvider.

As you can see in the JSONConfig all the keys/values are stored in a Map, the keys are in an Object class so they can be casted to anything.

So since i knew all the values in this case (in the core) would all be InformativeItemProviders i did let the all the values be casted to a InformativeItemProvider. And that is where it goes wrong.

The json is succesfully converted from a string to an map. 
But when i try to cast the object from the map to InformativeItemProvider (what it actually is) it gives me the error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a `Map<String,InformativeItemProvider>`?

Comment: Yes, so i can use this class for multiple configuration sets. without having to change the class everytime.

Comment: That's your problem unfortunately. There is no way Gson will know what kind of objects to create if you don't give it. Why don't you make your class generic instead? Given the simplicity here, you could even extract the file I/O and redo the Gson stuff for each independent use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the following `TypeToken`:

```
Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Map<String,Object>>() { }.getType();
```

You don't tell Gson anything about the type of objects you want it to create. Therefore, it will simply create the most vague objects representing JSON substructures: `LinkedTreeMap`s. That's why you get a `ClassCastException` if you try to cast these objects into something else.

A first solution to your problem is to use a `Map<String,InformativeItemProvider>` instead. And provide a TypeToken that actually gives information about the concrete type you want:

```
Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Map<String,InformativeItemProvider>>() { }.getType();
```

Then, if you want to re-use your class, you may first separate json parsing from file I/O, and you'll see there's almost nothing to reuse regarding the Gson part.